Java に比べ C# で ガベージコレクションの記事・話題が少ない理由は？
Java だとガベージコレクション (GC) のアルゴリズムやログに関する記事・話題が数多く存在しますが、C# では少ないように思います。この違いはどこからくるのでしょう。
使い方が違うから？
使われる場所が違うから？
Java で JVM へのメモリー割り当てや GC のログを観察したりとか、それって仕事増えてない？ C# だったらどうなの？って思って質問しました。
そもそも、C# と GC が無関係でしたらすみません。

GCの挙動で実際に困った事例があり、その解決策を探しているのであれば、質問をもっと具体的にしたほうがよいでしょう。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask をご確認ください。

raccyさんの回答通りと思います。.NETについて補足します。

.NETは初めからJavaVMの対抗として開発されていることもあってか、最初のリリースで世代別GCを搭載していたと考えられます。

はい、GC.MaxGenerationプロパティが.NET Framework 1.1から用意されている通り、.NETは当初より世代別GCです。

Microsoftのサイトで.NETのバージョン違いによるGCの動作の違いに関する文章は見つけられませんでした

ガベージ コレクションにまとめられています。

つまり、このときのGCは十分よく完成しており、JavaVMのようにバージョンアップの度にGCを追加したり、複数用意したりする必要は無かったと思われます。

ここは少し違います。当初から２つあり、バージョンアップで２つ追加されています。

サーバーGC

当初より存在する。
サービスのように長時間・マルチスレッド動作するプロセスを想定。
現在においてはワークステーションGCの改良によりほとんど大差なくそもそも知られていないことが多い。


ワークステーションGC

当初より存在する。
CLIなど短時間・シングルスレッド動作するプロセスを想定。
マルチスレッドの一般化により後述の改良が加えられる。


同時実行GC

.NET Framework 2.0？で登場、4.0でバックグラウンドGCに置き換え。
オプションで無効化できる。
GCによる停止時間が抑えられる。
この辺ちょっとあやふや…。


バックグラウンドGC

.NET Framework 4.0でワークステーションGCに登場し、4.5でサーバーGCにも登場。
オプションで無効化できる。
GCによる停止時間が更に抑えられる。




GCから少しだけ離れますが、C#（.NET）には構造体（値型）が存在します。この値型はGCを使用しません。（Javaにはこのような仕組みが存在しない？）
プログラマは構造体を使用することでGCを回避することができますし、そのことはGCの負担が低減されます。

まとめると、.NETは

JavaVMでの課題も踏まえてGCが設計されており、
プログラム形態に合うよう複数のGCが用意されており、
時代の変化に即して、問題が表面化する前に先回りしてGC改良が行われており、
それらは公式サイトで常に説明されている。

このため

多くのプログラマにとってGCをあまり意識する必要がなく、
GC問題に直面したプログラマはまずは構造体を用いることでGCの使用を回避でき、
それでも問題が解決しない場合は公式サイトを見ればよく、
したがって、GCについて積極的に発信する必要がない。

のだと思います。

こういうのは、ちゃんとした研究がおそらくないので全て憶測です。
言語と仮想マシンを混同している
対比関係があっていないため、全く見当違いのモノを比較している可能性があります。言語としてはJavaとC#が対比関係ですが、仮想マシンとしてはJavaVMと.NETが対比関係です。GCが実際に実装されているのは仮想マシン側であり、言語ではありません。言語としては、言語仕様としてGCを必須にしているかどうかや、GCを操作するためにどのようなAPIが提供されているかということぐらいです。GCの細かい動作、アルゴリズムや動作の特徴、チューニングの仕方などの多くは仮想マシンがどのようになっているかによります。つまり、あなたが「JavaのGCに関する文章」と思っているもののほとんどは「JavaVMのGCに関する文章」です。よって、それらと比較すべきなのは、「C#のGCに関する文章」ではなく、「.NETのGCに関する文章」ということになります。
つまり、「C#よりJavaの方がGCに関する文章が多い」と感じるのは、次のいずれかによる誤謬と考えられます。

Javaだと思っている文章のほとんどはJavaVMであり、実際よりも多くカウントしている。
言語と仮想マシンの組合せでの比較だとしても、.NETという言葉で検索していないため、多くの文章を逃してしまっている。

JavaとJavaVMの組合せは公式(Oracle)が認める唯一の組合せであるため、多くの人が混同している場合があることも一因かも知れません。Javaが動作するのはJavaVM以外にもARTがありますし、JavaVMで動作する言語にもKotlinやScalaがあり、それぞれの文章がARTやKotlin/Scalaでも当て嵌まるのか、当て嵌まらないのか考えると、どちらについて言及している文章なのか区別できるかと思います。
対して、.NETにはC#以外にF#やVB.NETという別言語が公式で用意されているので、ちゃんと区別して述べる文章が多いのだと思われます。
初期のJavaVMのGCの性能が悪すぎた
Javaが最初にリリースされたのは1995年です。このころはGCの研究自体がまだまだ進んでなかったと思われます。初期のJavaは循環参照を解消するためには単純なマーク・アンド・スイープ(M&S)方式を取っていたようですが、全てが停止するストップ・ザ・ワールド(STW)が長いことが問題でした。当初から、JavaVMはサーバーなどで長期間動作することを想定しており、GCはメモリリークの解消に貢献しましたが、STWで無反応な時が発生することは大きな問題でした。それから、如何にSTWの影響を小さくするのかがGCの改良の歴史となりました。その後、M&Sの改良版である世代別GCが開発され、JavaVMをアップデートする度に新たなGCを追加したりしてきました。このように、JavaVMのGCはSTWとの戦いの歴史であり、多くの問題と多くの実装があるため、それに関する文章も自ずと多くなっていると考えられます。
対して、.NETはどうかというと、.NET Frameworkのpre-betaが出てきたのが2000年です。この頃には世代別GCを搭載したJDK 1.3もリリースされています。.NETは初めからJavaVMの対抗として開発されていることもあってか、最初のリリースで世代別GCを搭載していたと考えられます。つまり、このときのGCは十分よく完成しており、JavaVMのようにバージョンアップの度にGCを追加したり、複数用意したりする必要は無かったと思われます(Microsoftのサイトで.NETのバージョン違いによるGCの動作の違いに関する文章は見つけられませんでした)。そのため、関連文章も自ずと少なくなったのではないかと思われます。

以上になりますが、文章が多いからどちらが優れているとか優れていないとかは判断できません。JavaVMは今でも複数のGCを選択できるようにしているようですし、.NETは今の実装で十分パフォーマンスが出ると考えているのかも知れません。


.NETという言葉で検索していないため、多くの文章を逃してしまっている

言語と仮想マシンの違いは理解しているのですが、私が検索に用いたキーワードの選定には工夫が足りないことに気づかされました。
ありがとうございます。

JavaVMのGCはSTWとの戦いの歴史であり、多くの問題と多くの実装があるため、それに関する文章も自ずと多くなっていると考えられます

そうですね。
私もそう感じました。
私が参考にした記事は、2002 年に書かれたものもあれば、2023 年に書かれたものまで多数ありました。
